# Parse key value from variable in shell script

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, variables

I want to extract all key value pairs from variable and need to reuse it.

Currently having variable with unicode dictionary.

```
a="u'{a': u'true', u'b': u'1', u'c': u'E', u'key': u'null', u'key1': u'null'}"
```

Tried to use `json.tool` from python in shell but it's with type file (unicode), so not able to get it.

Is it possible to just traverse variable in shell and print all key value pairs in shell

Tried below thing:

```
echo $a | python -c 'import json,sys; print type('sys.stdin')'
```

Output:

```
<type 'file'>
```

Note: We cant use `jq`.

Desired output which I need to re-use it:

```
a:true
b:1
c:E
key:null
key1:null
```

Above values I will re-use it in my script for putting it as key value.

Comment: Yes I need to get  key value pairs what you suggested

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: I don't know if this would work for what you want but you can evaluate a:
`eval(a)`
and then get the items like in a normal dictionary:
`eval(a).items()`

Comment: @Cyrus: I know json is not in valid format. So only asking whether we can traverse and print key value.

Comment: @n.qber: No its not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` command and `sed`

Try this

```
tr ',' '\n' <<< $a | cut -d"'" -f2,4| sed "s#^{##g;s#'#:#g"
```

Demo:

```
$echo $a
u'{a': u'true', u'b': u'1', u'c': u'E', u'key': u'null', u'key1': u'null'}
$tr ',' '\n' <<< $a | cut -d"'" -f2,4| sed "s#^{##g;s#'#:#g"
a:true
b:1
c:E
key:null
key1:null
$
```